# Json php formatted data

Tags: php, json

I have a json file like this

```
{
  "id": "123456789012345", 
  "members": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Dylan John", 
        "administrator": false, 
        "id": "12341234"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Test user", 
        "administrator": false, 
        "id": "43214321"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Demo user", 
        "administrator": false, 
        "id": "55445544"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "Fake user", 
        "administrator": false, 
        "id": "11991199"
      }
    ], 
    "paging": {
      "next": "www.123456demo12345.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to extract the id of each name.

I just start my php code like that but simply display only the master id:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.1234demo1234fake.com/user.json";

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo $data[id]; //echo master id
echo $data[members][data][id];
?>
```

Comment: Use quotes around key names like `echo $data['id']`, because otherwise you try to use constants values (that is not set)

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over `$data['members']['data']` and print `$data['members']['data'][$i]['id']`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object contains property `members` again `members` has property `data`.

Now `data` is an array.

Just loop over `data`, you get array of objects (members), fetch property `id` from it.

```
<?php
$abc = json_decode($your_json_sting);
$membersData = $abc->members->data;
$memberIds = array();
foreach ($membersData as $mem) {
    $memberIds[] = $mem->id;
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($memberIds);echo '</pre>';
?>
```